# How do you use a forward slash in a regex search?

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I am trying to find and replace all text in between comments in my react component using regex.

This is an example of the react component with comments:

```
<Text>{/*text1*/}hey hey hey{/*text1*/}</Text>
```

I am able to replace the text if I change `{/*text1*/}` to `{text1}`. The issue is whenever I try to add the `/* */` part of the comment into my regex it keeps adding an extra backslash.

Below is my current function that works if I remove the /* and */ from the comment in my component:

```
async function doIt(fileName, location, replacementText) {
  let tempRegex = "(?<={" + location + "})(.*)(?={" + location + "})"
  let regex = new RegExp(tempRegex)

  await fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, fileName), 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err
    content = data
    content = content.replace(regex, replacementText)

    fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, fileName), content, 'utf8', function (err) {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log('FILE SAVED')
    })
  })
}


doIt('change.js', "text1", 'test test')
```

My idea was to change my tempRegex to:

`"(?<={/*" + location + "*/})(.*)(?={/*" + location + "*/})"`

but it keeps adding extra characters and looks like this:

`/(?<={\/*textBox1*\/})(.*)(?={\/*textBox1*\/})/`

Is there a way to add forward slashes without it adding an extra backslash?

Comment: It doesn't add backslashes, this is just for printing.

Comment: Forward slashes have meaning in regex expressions, so if you want a literal forward slash to search on, you'll need to escape them. That's what the backslashes do.

Answer (score 1):

The forward slash `/` is a special character in regular expressions, because it denotes the beginning and the end of them. In case you want to target a forward slash *inside* your `RegExp` you have to escape it. That's what the backslashes do.

So this regular expression is invalid:

```
/{//
```

Whereas this one is valid:

```
/{\//
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized my issue was that new RegExp was not escaping the asterisk. This was my final solution. I had to add 2 backslashes in front of the asterisk for it to work.

```
export default function updateText(fileName, location, replacementText) {
  let tempRegex = "(?<={/\\*" + location + "\\*/})(.*)(?={/\\*" + location + "\\*/})"
  let regex = new RegExp(tempRegex)

  fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, fileName), 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err
    content = data
    content = content.replace(regex, replacementText)
    fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, fileName), content, 'utf8', function (err) {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log('FILE SAVED')
    })
  })
}
```